# How to translate description Command with Symfony and TranslatorInterface?

Tags: php, symfony, command, translation

I have a project using Symfony 3.4+ . The Translator component is well working.
I can use it in Command object in the execute method, but I cannot use it in the configure method. The translator is null.

```php
class TestCommand extends Command
{    
    /**
     * Translator.
     *
     * @var TranslatorInterface
     */
    protected $translator;

    /**
     * DownloadCommand constructor.
     *
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    protected function configure()
    {

        dump($this->translator);

        $this
            ->setName('app:test')
            ->setDescription('Test command description.')
            ->setHelp('Test command help.');
        //I cannot write $this->setHelp($this->translation->trans('...'));
        //because translator is still null
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): ?int
    {
        $output->writeln($this->translator->trans('command.test.translation'));

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Here is output :

> C:\test>php bin/console app:test
>
> command.test is well translated
>
> TestCommand.php on line 48: null

**Why translator interface is not initialized in configure method?**

**How to initialize translator interface in configure method?**

Comment: Can u try to set the the translator first and then call `parent::__construct()` ?

Comment: Thanks @Snegirekk, it works! I let u post the answer to validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base Command class [calls configure() method in its constructor](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Command/Command.php#L77). So if you 
want to use some autowired fields in your command configuration, you must set these fields first in your constructor and then call `parent::__construct();`, which calls `$this->configure();`

In your case the correct code should looks like this:

```
public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;

    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to configure your TestCommand config in services.yml file like this

```
#app/config/services.yml
AppBundle\Command\TestCommand:
    arguments:
        $translator: '@translator'
```